# User-defined Function in VBA Excel is Not Accessible?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, vbe

I have this function in a module in my VBE, but when I try to access it in my userforms, I get an error because it cannot be detected by VBE:
[image: Error]

This is the `Col_Letter` function:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

I also tried adding `Public`:

```
Public Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Your module is named `Col_Letter` as well. Change the name of the module and it would work.

Comment: I always prefix module names with 'm', class modules with 'cls'. Now I know why 8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming a module with the same name as a public funciton is quite a bad idea. Change the name of the `Col_Letter` module or the name of the function.

Comment: Right. I've been really confused as to why it's not working. Thanks

Comment: @MarcSantos - you are welcome. Making the function `public` was a good first step.

Comment: @MarcSantos Something that I find helps is to use a type-declaration prefix to objects and variable (e.g. `lng_Users` for a `Long` variable, `frm_Users` for a UserForm, `mod_Users` for a Module, etc) - it also makes it much easier when you review code at a later date to work out what everything is/does

Comment: @Chronocidal - this is a great article by the creator of StackOverflow, which goes 100% against this practice. Read it, it may change your coding style forever - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/